# How can I run aws cli commands in scheduled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, runbook

I'm trying to run AWS CLI commands every week for a backup. Basically, the commands that I want to run are:

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id "access_key" --profile user2 && aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "secret_key" --profile user2 && aws configure set region "us-east-2" --profile user2 && aws configure set output "text" --profile user2

aws s3 ls --endpoint-url=https://s3.wasabisys.com

aws s3 sync <SOURCE-BUCKET> <DESTINATION-BUCKET> --endpoint-url=https://s3.wasabisys.com
```

It works when I run these commands in AWS CloudShell, but I want to run them automatically every week. How can I achieve that?"

Comment: If you want to run AWS functionality on a schedule, write an AWS Lambda function in a supported programming language and then set a CRON Expression that determines the schedule it's invoked.

Comment: Why the azure tag? There's no mention of Azure anywhere in your question.

Comment: CloudShell stops running when it is not being used. Do you have a computer anywhere on the Internet that is running 24x7? If so, you can add a cron job (Linux) or Scheduled Task (Windows) to run these commands.